# How can I reduce the RMS value for a bridge rectifier?

Tags: rectifier, rms, bridge

[image]

I need to reduce the rectified DC voltage.  Is it possible to reduce the RMS value after the bridge rectifier i.e before the capacitor? Practical value (at the capacitor) is 34 DC voltage. I need to reduce this voltage.

Input is 24 VAC, output should be at least 26 V DC.  Input voltage is fixed.

Comment: For how much current?

Comment: 1.5 ampere max.(but practically am drawing around 800 milli amps)sir

Comment: Since the required current is relatively high and the voltage difference is enough, I would suggest using a DC/DC step-down converter.

Comment: right sir.but i will be drawing only 800 m amps . i tried with L.M.2596(DC TO DC BUCK CONVERTER) but the problem is there is too much heating sensation across the ic

Comment: The switch element in LM2596 is a BJT. That's why there's too much heat. Also please note that LM2596 requires a big copper area as heatsin. It would be better if you use an IC with internal MOSFET (like L5973 or TPS54340).

Comment: @RohatKılıç The LM2596 can be efficient but I think that the voltage difference between input and output is a bit too small in this case. I agree that a more modern DCDC converter can do a better job.

Comment: insert a 1 ohm or a 4.7 ohm resistor. These will get hot.

Comment: @ analogsystemsrf yes i already tried with the same values with higher wattage(1 watt) they are heating rapidly.

Comment: can any one tell why  am i getting 35 voltage across the capacitor.(practically it is boosting the voltage).i have consider the r.m.s values calculation i need to know some theoretical approach.why and how this 35 volt at capacitor.please help.thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

You could simply add a couple of diodes to drop the voltage:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foadTO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

each diode will drop about 1 V, you can add more if needed.

The "proper" way to do this is of course to use a transformer with the right output voltage. This diode trick is a bit of a "hack" but that might be all you need.

Comment: Would a Z-Diode to GND also be working?

Comment: @AlexandervonWernherr **Only** a zener diode: no. Imagine if the AC voltage from the left can deliver large amounts of current, then a large current will flow through the zener diode as it tries to limit the voltage. To solve this a series resistor (instead of D5, D6) would be needed. Even then the resistor and zenerdiode will burn a lot of power. It is a **power inefficient** solution. A zener diode in series can also work but it needs to be high power (a couple of Watt) and low voltage, these are hard to find. Using diodes is simple and easy.

Comment: An alternative would be a thyristor chopper circuit that would allow for adjustable output. I don't know how complicated OP is willing to go with this though.

Comment: thank you everyone i will try working on your points.appreciated your efforts.